# Как определить Internal Storage, SD card, usb?

Tags: android

Для получения списка хранилищ нашел единственный рабочий код на 5-9 андроидах (Проверил на своих устройствах и эмуляторах)

```
public HashSet<String> getExternalMounts() {
        final HashSet<String> out = new HashSet<String>();
        String reg = "(?i).*vold.*(vfat|ntfs|exfat|fat32|ext3|ext4).*rw.*";
        String s = "";
        try {
            final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("mount")
                    .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            process.waitFor();
            final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
                s = s + new String(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // parse output
        final String[] lines = s.split("\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (!line.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("asec")) {
                if (line.matches(reg)) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    for (String part : parts) {
                        if (part.startsWith("/"))
                            if (!part.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("vold"))
                                out.add(part);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Но как с его помощью определять к какому устройству полученный путь относится?

Для нуги и более новых версий есть вариант

```
val sm: StorageManager = getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
val sv = sm.storageVolumes
```

Но он не работает на устаревших версиях, хотя и с его помощью как можно отличить sd карта или usb накопитель подключен?